# Is the maximum degree of a planar graph 5?

Tags: planar-graphs

I'm trying to study (by myself) planar graphs. On the book I'm reading, I came across this sentence about the 5-coloring problem that I really don't understand:

> Lemma 5.8.15. Every planar graph has a vertex of degree at most five.
>
> Proof. By contradiction. If every vertex had degree at least 6, then the sum of the
> vertex degrees is at least 6v, but since the sum of the vertex degrees equals 2e, by
> the Handshake Lemma (Lemma 5.2.1), we have e  3v contradicting the fact that
> e  3v <= 6 < 3v by Theorem 5.8.6.

I don't get why a planar graph has a vertex of degree at most five. If I take the 9-star graph there will be a node with degree 9 and the graph will still be planar so the maximum degree is greater than 6.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the 9-star graph. You are right that the MAXIMUM degree will be 9 > 6, but the MINIMUM degree is found at the other end of the edges and equals 1. The claim is not that EVERY degree < 6, just that there is always one.

Comment: The proof you quote misses at least one '='-sign and perhaps some other symbols which I can not reverse engeneer. Can you go back to the original source and edit it?

Comment: BTW don't feel stupid for not immediately 'seeing' that this is true - it is really a somewhat surprising fact that really needs a proof. The proof (which can be found in some of the 'Related' questions in the sidebar) relies on Euler's formula v - e + f = 2 which in itself is not at all obvious at first sight.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand... If you feel like posting an actual answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the claim is not that the maximum degree is 5 (that would be wrong by exactly your reasoning) but that the minimum degree is 5 or less. Some planar graphs have minimum degree 1, some minimum degree 2, etc but no planar graph has minimum degree 6. This is not obvious, hence we need a proof.

Minimum degree 6 means 'every vertex has degree at least six', that is why the book starts its proof by looking at a hypothetical graph where every vertex has degree at least six and proceeds to show that no such graph can exist.